# How to disable tkinter Menu

Tags: python, tkinter, button, window

This is my code below. I want a tkinter window which does not have option to close at the top right. It should either be hidden or disabled. I tried multiple things online but it was all in vein. If someone could help, will be very glad. Thank You.

```
class RegisterClass(SendOtp):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.window = Tk()
            self.window.title("Register")
            self.window.geometry("925x500+300+200")
            self.window.configure(bg="#fff")
            self.window.resizable(False, False)
```

edit:
I got `self.window.overrideredirect(1)` which could completely remove the above menu bar but it just looks ugly. Anything I could just disable the buttons and not completely vanish them?

Comment: What have you tried? (What are the "multiple things online")

Comment: @realhuman by multiple things online meant the edited part and some lame things X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Way one `overrideredirect`

This will hide the whole top bar of the tkinter window.

```
from tkinter import *
class RegisterClass(SendOtp):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.window = Tk()
            self.window.title("Register")
            self.window.overrideredirect(True)
            self.window.geometry("925x500+300+200")
            self.window.configure(bg="#fff")
            self.window.resizable(False, False)
```

Way two `wm_protocol`

Here whenever the user clicks `X` self.onClosing function execute.

```
from tkinter import *
class RegisterClass(SendOtp):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.window = Tk()
            self.window.title("Register")
            self.window.geometry("925x500+300+200")
            self.window.configure(bg="#fff")
            self.window.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.onClosing)
            self.window.resizable(False, False)
    def onClosing(self):
        pass
        # Write your code for what you want whenever the user clicks the `X` button. # self.window.destroy() for closing the window if you want.
```